# Find an iconic movie title with these 8 numbers...!

Tags: cipher, music, movies

Here is a code with symbols as hints (Note: The footnote on the second page has nothing to do with the puzzle, it's just there for copyright purposes):

[image: RiddlePage1]

[image: RiddlePage2]

I am psyched to find out if or how somebody cracks it (there are two paths to the solution). The solution is the title of a movie.

Hint (added 24. Oct.)

> Scale (music)

Second Hint (added 04/04 '18)

> you know there are other numeral systems

Third Hint (added 28/06 '22)

> Combine the C-Major Scale (normal white keys on a piano) with a septenary numeral system (base 7)

Have fun!

Comment: Are you sure this should be tagged with [tag:music] and not [tag:movies]?

Comment: Yes I am, you could do both...

Comment: It could be something like 'LICENCE TO KILL'...as the given numbers when mapped to alphabets reversedly (that is z=1, y=2, and so on till a=26) we get letters needed for the title(partially, though). Gun adds to it. Piano cannot be linked though!

Comment: If you just look at it as an alphabetic cipher, it takes the form "ABCDABCE."  At first, I thought, "Eureka! 'Hot Shots!' " but that isn't it.  (I even checked the movie poster, just to see if they had an 's' reversed, but no luck.). Still, I am a bit suspicious of those repeated numbers . . .)

Comment: Does it require knowledge of piano notes to solve

Comment: It doesn't "require" previous knowledge, since everything in music theory is highly logical (especially around the piano) and can be researched. It's pretty simple but not obvious :)

Answer (score 4):

> The Godfather

My reasoning

> If I interpret the numbers as keys on the piano from the left, they sound like the beginning of the theme of the movie, plus the second hint is a gun.

Comment: I am afraid to tell you it is not this one. The corresponding notes with the keys can be different on any piano or keyboard, and there's a universal solution. Funny that this is how your piano is arranged, did you count with or without the half step keys? Going to try this myself :)

Comment: Without. Although I think I was reading into it a bit much, it's not that alike. Also, I know next to nothing about music!

Comment: I just understood the way you tried this back then, it's almost correct. Maybe you can try again with the hints ;)

Answer (score 1):

it might be

> Grand piano (spanish movie)

Reasons why :

> The numbers can be split in two sequences where only the last one change, so I thought maybe a plot twist. Then I searched for a movie with a piano and a gun, and I found Grand piano where a musician return to perform and I don't know why but a sniper take him as a target and will kill him if he plays a single wrong note. The difference in the two sequence is now explained, it shows the right and wrong note, two paths that can lead to the death of the main character.

Comment: Amazing reasoning, reads like a beautifully written interpretation of a poem. But unfortunately just an interpretation... You can be reassured when I say iconic it has to be at least one of the top 20 on IMDb ;)

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the movie is :

> Inception

Reasoning:

> I was thinking about famous movies and that's when it struck me that the keyboard represents music, and the gun represents death. When combined, death follows music. 
> One movie that follows this approach is Inception where, in cue with the music, the characters are killed in the dreams that they occupy, in order for them to wake up into reality after they've completed their respective jobs. This process is referred to as the kick. Meanwhile, the numbers could be related to the time dilation of the dream levels or the minutes they take up in the movie, with the shortest amount going for reality.

Another line of reasoning:

> Up until the last part of the movie, the music was what cued the kick. But in Limbo, a gun was needed for Saito to escape limbo.

Please Feel free to edit to improve this answer to make it more understandable for users.

Comment: Unfortunately It's not Inception. Albeit very nice reasoning ;)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

This may be...

> The Pianist (2002)

Cipher:

> Not very sure about this but it sounds like the first part of the soundtrack '[Nocturne in C-sharp minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturne_in_C-sharp_minor,_Op._posth._(Chopin))'

Clue:

> The movie tells a story of pianist and composer Władysław Szpilman is backdrop of WWII. It weaves beautifully music and violence represented by the piano and the gun.

Comment: If this were the reasoning, King Kong and Toy Story would be equally valid answers, so I think this cannot be correct.

Comment: @Bass : if we assume it's some kind of letters to numbers cipher, you want a repeating letter pair like 'ab' 'cd' or 'rs' in title to co-related with repeating numbers 14 and 15 in the cipher text

Answer (score 0):

> Given the recent hint It could be converted to binary
>
>  6 = 00110110 (assuming ascii)
>  or
>  6 = 110 (dec to binary)
>  According to the wiki article on scales you can have 12 bits represent each of the twelve notes of a chromatic scale.
>
>  I don't know enough about music to go farther than this but maybe someone else does.

Comment: There are also other scales (very basic and used in almost all western songs) that have a different bases :) good starting point!

Answer (score 0):

Just putting it out there:

> Using **Location arithmetic** where 2^0=1=a; 2^1=2=b,... I get this: 
>     6  = 2+4 (bc) 
>     12 = 4+8 (cd) 
>     14 = 2+4+8 (bcd) 
>     15 = 1+2+4+8 (abcd) 
>     21 = 1+4+16 (ace) 
>  Which based on the pattern: **6 14 15 12 6 14 15 21** leads to: **bc bcd abcd cd bc bcd abcd ace**

Comment: When seeing patterns you need to combine it with the other clues (keyboard). Interesting arithmetics though, I think you could expand it to the solution even when there are easier paths...